# Consulta SQL que devuelva los 3 lugares que más se repiten en la BD

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Siento ser pesado, Llevo desde el viernes pasado atascado y necesito hacer una consulta SQL sobre una base de datos mySQL. La base de datos crea un nuevo registro siempre que alguien pulsa el boton de "Buscar" en la pagina y tengo que acceder a esa información para sacar datos estadisticos y representarlos por php.

Consulta que yo tengo.

```
SELECT count(*) As canti , CONCAT(CodArea,':',CodCity) As Lugar
FROM statssearch
where STR_TO_DATE(Fecini,'%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('2017','%Y')
GROUP BY fecha
                              //Obtiene el lugar que mas se repite de cada mes.
```

Necesitio es que obtenga los 3 sitios mas buscados de cada mes.
Ejemplo del resultado que necesito:

```
    Mes   Lugar   Lugar2    Lugar3
    -----------------------------------------  
   enero   416      134       7811
 febrero   33       440        14
        .
        .
diciembre  123     32434      5434
```

La base de datos tiene esta estructura:
[image: Estructura BD]
Espero vuestras respuestas. =D

Comment: ¿Podrías poner datos de ejemplo de entrada y de salida? Es complejo y nos dedica mucho tiempo hacer una consulta anidada con datos y esquemas inventados por ingeniería inversa. Es muy probable que haya que jugar con GROUP_CONCAT y FIND_IN_SET para anidar consultas en las que salgan los 3 máximos por cada fecha.

Comment: Por ejemplo necesito que en 'Lugar1' 'Lugar2' y 'Lugar3' aparezcan los lugares que más se repitan para despues poder representar la consulta en un grafico estadistico. Gracias

Comment: Por favor, con ejemplos en tu pregunta y datos de entrada y salida de ejemplo. La imaginación, cuando tenemos muchas otras preguntas y cosas de nuestra vida diaria, nos puede jugar malas pasadas y hacernos perder tiempo hasta que entendemos del todo lo que quieres. Gracias. Echa un vistazo a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: No te entiendo con lo de ejemplos de entrada

Comment: Mira el enlace que te he puesto y verás qué ejemplos ofrece y mira la segunda respuesta, es muy probable que sea la que buscas.

Comment: He reproducido y solucionado tu problema, aunque he tenido que ignorar en gran medida la consulta SQL que pones de ejemplo ya que despista más que ayuda. En cuanto reabran la pregunta expondré la respuesta (he tenido que guardarla en un archivo txt porque no me deja publicarla). Es una consulta anidada de tres niveles que puede servir de ejemplo para muchos otros usuarios que quieran hacer lo mismo.

Comment: He realizado otra pregunta en el que pongo más claro lo que necesito pero si puedes publicar la respuesta sería de mucha ayuda ya que como dices es de gran ayuda para otros usuarios.

Comment: He votado "reabrir" para que puedas poner tu respuesta @OscarGarcia

Comment: Suelen ser reabiertas las preguntas?

Comment: Cuando editas y mejoras una pregunta, automaticamente pasan a una cola de revisión donde los usuarios del sitio pueden votar para reabrir la pregunta.

Comment: Ya he hecho lo que me dijiste. También borré las otras preguntas. Espero que se abrá pronto.

Comment: Ya tiene 4 votos de reapertura. Solo falta uno.

Comment: Ya esta reabierta! asi que solo queda esperar a que nos comente @OscarGarcia, Gracias por el apoyo. :)

Comment: Repito lo mismo que te dije en tu respuesta borrada: no veo ningún error, sólo marcas rojas. ¿Podrías incluir también el texto de los mensajes de error? También me vendría bien tu versión de tu MySQL y phpmyadmin. Con eso podría reproducir mejor tu problema. Recuerda que también sería conveniente conocer el esquema exacto de tu tabla y un pequeño volcado de datos, y no la aproximación que hice, que podría ser origen de los errores.

Comment: SELECT VERSION(); Me ha devuelto esto: 10.1.19. me gustaría darte como valida tu respuesta alguna solucion para cambiar de version o adaptar tu query para que funcione en mi ordenador?

Comment: ahora formulo de nuevo la respuesta, primero dime a que te refieres con añadir formatos?

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con `group_concat`, que al agrupar, te concatena en forma de lista todos los valores que han sido agrupados separados por coma y ordenados por el criterio que quieras (`a,b,c,d`). Luego, con `find_in_set` puedes obtener el índice de un elemento particular.

La idea sería obtener una tabla A agrupada por mes y zona, con las repeticiones de cada zona en cada mes. Como esta tabla la vamos a necesitar dos veces, creamos una vista (que se puede utilizar como tabla):

```
create view cantitbl as
select count(*) as canti, statssearch.*,
       date_format(fecini, '%Y-%m') as mes,
       concat(codcity, '/', codarea) as zone
from statssearch group by mes, zone;

select * from cantitbl;

+-------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------+
| canti | codcity | codarea | fecini     | mes     | zone  |
+-------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------+
|     3 | 15      | 8       | 2017-04-12 | 2017-04 | 15/8  |
|     2 | 10      | 10      | 2017-04-12 | 2017-04 | 10/10 |
|     1 | 6       | 1       | 2017-04-14 | 2017-04 | 6/1   |
|     1 | 5       | 12      | 2017-04-12 | 2017-04 | 5/12  |
|     4 | 15      | 8       | 2017-05-11 | 2017-05 | 15/8  |
|     3 | 10      | 10      | 2017-05-12 | 2017-05 | 10/10 |
|     1 | 20      | 6       | 2017-05-14 | 2017-05 | 20/6  |
|     1 | 6       | 1       | 2017-05-13 | 2017-05 | 6/1   |
|     1 | 5       | 12      | 2017-05-12 | 2017-05 | 5/12  |
|     1 | 20      | 6       | 2017-06-14 | 2017-06 | 20/6  |
+-------+---------+---------+------------+---------+-------+
```

La barra entre la ciudad y el área es necesaria para que 5/12 no se confunda con 51/2, por ejemplo.

Luego agrupamos por mes la tabla A, en la tabla B, pero obteniendo a su vez la lista de "zonas" de dicho mes ordenadas por repeticiones (con `group_concat`):

```
create view maxrep as
select mes, group_concat(zone order by canti desc) as zonelist
from cantitbl group by mes;

select * from maxrep order by mes;

+---------+--------------------------+
| mes     | zonelist                 |
+---------+--------------------------+
| 2017-04 | 15/8,10/10,5/12,6/1      |
| 2017-05 | 15/8,10/10,5/12,6/1,20/6 |
| 2017-06 | 20/6                     |
+---------+--------------------------+
```

Y luego, volver a cruzar la tabla de repeticiones (A) con la agrupada por meses (B) obtiendo solo aquellas filas de la primera (A) que estén en las tres primeras posiciones de la lista agrupada de la segunda (B). El índice de la zona en la lista la podemos saber con `find_in_set`:

```
select ct.canti, ct.codcity, ct.codarea, ct.mes
from cantitbl as ct
inner join maxrep as mr
      on ct.mes = mr.mes and
      find_in_set(ct.zone, mr.zonelist) between 1 and 3
order by ct.mes, ct.canti desc;

+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| canti | codcity | codarea | mes     |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
|     3 | 15      | 8       | 2017-04 |
|     2 | 10      | 10      | 2017-04 |
|     1 | 5       | 12      | 2017-04 |
|     4 | 15      | 8       | 2017-05 |
|     3 | 10      | 10      | 2017-05 |
|     1 | 5       | 12      | 2017-05 |
|     1 | 20      | 6       | 2017-06 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Si quieres hacerlo en una sola consulta, solo tendrías que sustituir `cantitbl` por el `select` que define a la vista, y lo mismo con `maxrep` (que a su vez, incluye de nuevo a `cantitbl`; tendrías que sustituir la consulta dos veces).

Observa que no he añadido `order by` cláusulas en las vistas, ya que ahí aún no hacen falta, así las consultas son más cortas. Solo son necesarias en el `select` final.

Por último, para filtrar por año, dado que semánticamente las vistas son correctas, ya que Abril del 2016 no es lo mismo que Abril de 2017, solo es necesario especificar el filtro y el formato de la tabla deseados en el `select` final:

```
select ct.canti, ct.codcity, ct.codarea, month(ct.fecini) as mes
from cantitbl as ct
inner join maxrep as mr
      on ct.mes = mr.mes and
      find_in_set(ct.zone, mr.zonelist) between 1 and 3
where year(ct.fecini) == 2017
order by ct.mes, ct.canti desc;
```

Comment: ¿No tenerlo en cuenta donde? ¿En el select final, en la agrupación, ...? Por una cuestión semántica, las vistas (que no se ejecutan hasta que no se utilizan), el año hay que tenerlo en cuenta. Si quieres filtrar el año en el select final, solo tienes que jugar con `date_format` o `month`, `year`, etc, para filtrar y mostrar lo que quieras.

Answer (score 0):

A tu count(*) colocale algo así como

```
count(*) as contar
```

cosa que despues al final, puedas recurrir a ordenarlo descendente

```
order by contar desc
```

Así, colocándole los valores de búsqueda que eso lo ves tu, según la estructura de tabla que esta definida en la base de datos.

Adicionalmente entendiendo cual es tu petición por medio de los comentarios. Debes dejar de agrupar por fecha, y solo agrupar por

```
Concat(t1.codcity, t1.codarea)
```

Ya que agrupara este termino, y solo como condición le colocas el rango de fecha. Lo que quedaria tu codigo algo similar a esto

```
SELECT Count(*)                                  AS canti, 
       Concat(t1.codcity, t1.codarea)            AS Lugar, 
       Month(Str_to_date(t1.fecini, '%d-%m-%Y')) AS fecha 
FROM   statssearch t1, 
       statssearch t2 
WHERE  t1.fecini = t2.fecini 
       AND Str_to_date(t1.fecini, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN 
           Str_to_date('2017', '%Y') AND Curdate() 
       AND Str_to_date(t2.fecini, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN 
           Str_to_date('2017', '%Y') AND Curdate() 
       AND ROWNUM <= 3
GROUP  BY Concat(t1.codcity, t1.codarea)
ORDER BY canti
```

Comment: Ese no es el resultado que necesito, lo que necesito es en el 'As Lugar1, As Lugar2, As Lugar3' me aparezcan distintos codigos. Gracias

Comment: ¿Entonces por qué lo has marcado como respuesta correcta? Te he dejado un comentario para que nos pongas algo del esquema y datos con los que trabajar (para facilitarnos el trabajo de probar).

Comment: pues agrupalas por Concat(t1.codcity, t1.codarea) adicionalmente. Y no entiendo por que estas agrupando la fecha. Esa debiera de ser solo una condición, no parte de la condición, por que sino también te va a extender el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que quieres es lo siguiente:

```sql
SET @posicion = NULL, @valor = NULL;
SELECT mes,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(codigo, ' (', numero, ')') SEPARATOR ',') resultado
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      @posicion := IF(@valor = mes, @posicion + 1, 1) posicion,
      @valor := mes AS valor
    FROM (
      SELECT
        CONCAT(codcity, ':', codarea) codigo,
        Month(fecini) mes,
        COUNT(*) numero
      FROM
        statssearch
      GROUP BY mes, codigo
      ORDER BY mes, numero DESC
    ) tabla_interna
  ) tabla_externa
  WHERE posicion BETWEEN 1 AND 3
  ORDER BY mes, numero
) tabla_final
GROUP BY mes
```

Como puedes ver he hecho una consulta SQL anidada de cuatro niveles.

En la consulta interior (`tabla_interna`) obtengo un listado de meses con la suma ordenado por la suma y mes.

En la consulta exterior (`tabla_externa`) hago un recuento de posición dentro de cada mes, asignando números consecutivos a cada posición dentro de la repetición de un mismo mes.

En la consulta final (`tabla_final`) limito la posición del 1 al 3, para eliminar todo lo que quede fuera del top 3.

Y en último lugar, en la consulta más externa, agrupo por mes y concateno los registros encontrados en un único campo.

Para reproducir tu problema he usado el siguiente esquema de tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statssearch` (
  `codcity` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `codarea` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fecini` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codcity`,`codarea`,`fecini`),
  KEY `fecini` (`fecini`)
);
```

Con los siguientes datos de ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO `statssearch` (`codcity`, `codarea`, `fecini`) VALUES
('15', '8', '2017-04-12 08:40:39'),('5', '12', '2017-04-12 08:40:39'),('10', '10', '2017-04-12 12:40:39'),
('5', '12', '2017-04-12 16:40:39'),('15', '8', '2017-04-13 08:40:39'),('15', '8', '2017-04-14 08:40:39'),
('10', '10', '2017-04-14 15:31:39'),('15', '8', '2017-04-14 15:32:39'),('10', '10', '2017-04-14 15:33:39'),
('5', '12', '2017-04-14 15:34:39'),('15', '8', '2017-04-14 15:35:39'),('15', '8', '2017-04-14 15:36:39'),
('15', '8', '2017-05-12 08:40:39'),('6', '1', '2017-05-12 08:40:39'),('10', '10', '2017-05-12 12:40:39'),
('10', '10', '2017-05-12 16:40:39'),('15', '8', '2017-05-13 08:40:39'),('15', '8', '2017-05-14 08:40:39'),
('10', '10', '2017-05-14 15:31:39'),('15', '8', '2017-05-14 15:32:39'),('6', '1', '2017-05-14 15:33:39'),
('10', '10', '2017-05-14 15:34:39'),('20', '6', '2017-05-14 15:35:39'),('20', '6', '2017-05-14 15:36:39');
```

La consulta interna devuelve:

```
codigo mes numero
15:8     4      6
10:10    4      3
5:12     4      3
10:10    5      4
15:8     5      4
20:6     5      2
6:1      5      2
```

La consulta externa obtiene:

```
codigo mes numero posicion valor
15:8     4      6        1     4
10:10    4      3        2     4
5:12     4      3        3     4
10:10    5      4        1     5
15:8     5      4        2     5
20:6     5      2        3     5
6:1      5      2        4     5
```

Por lo que la consulta final deja únicamente los tres primeros de cada mes:

```
codigo mes numero posicion valor
15:8     4      6        1     4
10:10    4      3        2     4
5:12     4      3        3     4
10:10    5      4        1     5
15:8     5      4        2     5
20:6     5      2        3     5
```

Donde vemos eliminada la fila que estaba en cuarta posición del mes 5 (`6:1`).

Por último, tendríamos una agrupación por mes y concatenación del grupo en el campo `resultado`:

```
mes resultado
4   15:8 (6),5:12 (3),10:10 (3)
5   10:10 (4),15:8 (4),20:6 (2)
```

PD: Las concatenaciones las hecho con dos puntos <kbd>:</kbd> para separar `codcity` de `codarea` y una coma <kbd>,</kbd> para los grupos de cada mes, añadiendo entre paréntesis el número de veces que está ese registro dicho mes.

Comment: Gracias pero he metido en phpmyadmin tu respuesta y me salen muchos errores

Comment: Dime los errores o modifica tu pregunta con el esquema exacto de tu tabla y datos de ejemplo para que tenga en cuenta cualquier particularidad de tu tabla que no he tenido en cuenta en mi prueba de concepto.